# Conditional Poisson Distribution is Binomial

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

I need to show that if Xi ∼ Poisson(λi), i = 1, 2, . . . , k are independent then the conditional distribution of X1 given X1 + X2 + . . .Xk is Binomial and determines the parameters of this Binomial distribution. I tried:

$$ P(X1 = x| X1+...+Xk = y)$$

$$=\frac{P(X1 = x)P(X1+...+Xk = y|X1= x)}{P(X1 +...+Xk = y)}$$

$$=\frac{P(X1=x, X1+...+Xk = y)}{P(X1+...+Xk = y)}$$

$$=\frac{P(X1 = x)P(X2+...+Xk = y-x)}{\sum_{m=0}^yP(X1=m)P(X2+...+Xk = y-m) }$$

$$=\frac{λ1^xexp(-λ1)/x! *\frac{(λ2 + ...+λk)^{y-x}exp(-[λ2+...+λk])}{(y-x)!} }{\sum_{m=0}^y\frac{λ1^mexp(-λ1)}{m!} * \frac{(λ2 + ...+λk)^{y-m}exp(-[λ2+...+λk])}{(y-m)!} }$$

Then I am completely stuck. Am I on the right track? How do I get the $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ for the $nCk$ in the Binomial distribution? Any help is greatly appreciated.

--
Edit:
I have managed to get to the following:

$$=\frac{\frac{λ1^xexp(-λ1)}{x!} *\frac{(λ2 + ...+λk)^{y-x}exp(-[λ2+...+λk])}{(y-x)!} }   { \frac{(λ1 + ...+λk)^{y}exp(-[λ1+...+λk])} { y!}}$$
$$= \frac{y!}{x!{y-x}!}*\frac{λ1^x (λ2+...+λk)^{y-x}}{(λ1+...+λk)^y}$$

where I think I got the $nCk$ but not the $p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ bit. How can I simplify this step further? Sorry if this is really straightforward. What is $λ1+...+λk$? Can they sum up to 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your numerator is correct at
$$P(X_1=x, X_2+\cdots+X_k=y-x)=\frac{e^{-\lambda_1}\lambda_1^x}{x!}\cdot \frac{e^{-(\lambda_2+\cdots+\lambda_k)}(\lambda_2+\cdots+\lambda_k)^{y-x}}{(y-x)!}
$$
but your denominator is needlessly complex. Recall that, by independence, $X_1+\cdots+X_k$ has Poisson($\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_k$) distribution, so the denominator is simply
$$
P(X_1+\cdots+X_k=y)=\frac{e^{-(\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_k)}(\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_k)^y}{y!}.
$$
Computing the ratio of numerator over denominator, you should get some cancellation, and ${}_yC_x$ should pop out.

As a hint to uncover the binomial distribution, it will help to write
$(\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_k)^y$
in the form $(\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_k)^x(\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_k)^{y-x}$.

Comment: Hi grand_chat, thank you so much for helping me see the form of the denominator! I tried again but stuck at the last bit, could you please see the question edit? Btw, was it supposed to be $P(X1+⋯+Xk=y)$ rather than $P(Y1+⋯+Yk=y)$ in your answer?

Comment: @nilsinelabore  You are right, I have replaced the $Y$'s with $X$'s. As for the question edit, use the hint in the last sentence of my answer. The sum $\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_k$ cannot be simplified; it doesn't equal anything special.

Comment: I got it, thanks so much for your help!